# Url security trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I know that's old question, but I don't understand why code, that worked half a year ago doesn't work.
So I want to make only owners can have access to their posts. I thaught it could be written like this:

```
   def create
   @post = current_user.posts.new params[:post]
  if @post.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Post created'
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render :new
  end
    end
```

and in edit and others controllers

```
     def edit
       if (current_user.id == @post.user_id)
    @post = Post.find params[:id]
  else
    flash[:notice] = 'You are not owner!'
  end
end|
```

but in views I get, when I'm logged in:

```
 undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass
```

Where is my problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def edit
  # The @post is nil unless you set it in a before filter.
  if (current_user.id == @post.user_id)
    @post = Post.find params[:id]
  else
    flash[:notice] = 'You are not owner!'
  end
end
```

You should find the post first.

```
def edit
  @post = Post.find params[:id]
  if (current_user.id != @post.user_id)
    flash[:notice] = 'You are not owner!'
  end
end
```